# Spain: non-resident declare assets over 55,000 EUR?

Tags: taxes, non-resident, assets, spain, hard-assets

My mother was a resident in Spain previously, however this was before they changed law forcing you to declare all assets over 55,000 Euro. Back then she did not have any assets within the UK.

I am referring to this article:

> http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/mortgageshome/article-2317127/Expats-head-home-Spain-forced-declare-overseas-assets.html

Now my mother lives in the UK as a resident. She is named on a house worth over 55,000 Euro.

She has no connections to Spain, except the house there which she has a mortgage on. She is non-resident in Spain, pays non-residence tax of around 80 EUR.

**Question:** Does my mum need to declare all assets outside of Spain over 55,000 EUR even though she is a non-resident? Websites are saying she does not, however her accountant has given her the forms to declare her assets saying she does!

We got destroyed terribly by an accountant in Spain before (actually everyone I know has or knows someone that has - this is not the only problem we have had there). We are scared of having another problem as the Spanish system has caused us over 10 years of pain and suffering.

I know it is just declaring assets not paying tax, however we have less than 0 faith in Spain after living there, and like many are worried that Spain will grab our assets like Cyprus did to people living there.

Sorry for any disrespect. I hope people can give me some feedback as I am very scared.

Comment: You got scammed by an accountant and not the Spanish government. So you cannot blame the Spanish government for that. If you don't follow the law then yes your assets can be confiscated. Declare your assets as required by law, there is no harm doing that. If you have evidence against the accountant, take him to the courts for redressal.

Comment: @DumbCoder We cannot take him to court, by Spanish law what happened is our fault. Forgetting my past experiences (although I would like to add I am scared due to police corruption and other problems with the government). My mum is not a resident, does she still need to declare assets?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but you could try to get a second accountant to give you an opinion and you could try to do your own research (presumably you speak Spanish). Living in the UK, I've also known stories of accountants telling fairytales.